# Error in the Query (2)

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT m_name, m_status, p_num, p_date, g_code GROUP_CONCAT(g_code)
  FROM  (SELECT D.m_name, D.m_status, A.p_num, A.p_date, C.g_code 
           FROM post A 
                   LEFT OUTER JOIN postgoods B 
                          ON A.p_num = B.p_num
                   LEFT OUTER JOIN goodscode C 
                          ON B.g_num = C.g_num JOIN member D ON A.m_num = D.m_num
         ORDER BY A.p_date desc)
GROUP BY p_num
```

I do not know whether this code where the error

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

you are missing a  comma here

```
SELECT ... g_code, GROUP_CONCAT(g_code)
                 ^
```

### edit

U are also missing a table alias for your subselect (I named it `z`). Try

```
SELECT m_name, m_status, p_num, p_date, g_code, GROUP_CONCAT(g_code)
FROM  (SELECT D.m_name, D.m_status, A.p_num, A.p_date, C.g_code 
       FROM post A 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN postgoods B ON A.p_num = B.p_num
       LEFT OUTER JOIN goodscode C ON B.g_num = C.g_num 
       JOIN member D ON A.m_num = D.m_num
       ORDER BY A.p_date desc) z
GROUP BY p_num
```

You can use MySQL Workbench to run your query. It is free. And it will output the error of your query.

Comment: But, due to continued failure